# not able to get json response from nestjs route handler

Tags: nestjs

Why I am not getting the desired output as i given in res variable for returning from this route

```
  @Get('/signout')
  signOut(@Session() session: any) {
    session.userId = null;
    let res = JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify({
       status: 'success',
    }),
   );
console.log( "--> ", res);

if (!session.userId) {
  return res;
 }
}
```

i am getting empty json object as response

```
{}
```

i tried printing out my res var it outputs fine.

Comment: Why do you stringify and parse it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json response can be generated with two ways in NestJs, either use response object of express Response, or just add a header on the top of route handler method

1. Solution with applying header;

```
@Get('/')    
@Header('Content-type', 'application/json')

handleGet(){
     return JSON.stringify({ status : "success"})
    }
```

2. Solution with using response imported from Express.

   ```
   @Get('/')    
   @Header('Content-type', 'application/json')
   handleGet(@Response() res : Response){
     return res.json({ status : "success"});
   }
   ```

These are the two possible ways that i found to return JSON response from a route handler method. further if all your responses need to be JSON, you may create an interceptor to alter your response before it is sent

Answer (score 0):

To help debug your code have you tried just returning the response without any logic ?

```js
  @Get('/signout')
  signOut(@Session() session: any) {
  
    const res = {
       status: 'success',
    }

    console.log( "--> ", JSON.stringify(res));
  
    return res;
}
```

and then try

```js
  @Get('/signout')
  signOut(@Session() session: any) {
    session.userId = null;
    
    const res = {
       status: 'success',
    };

    console.log( "--> ", JSON.stringify(res));

    if (!session.userId) {
      return res;
    } else {
      throw new HttpException('Error', 500);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes i tried debugging, but it didnt worked, still thanks for the response and help